# Preserve Vaadin session data

Tags: session, authentication, vaadin

I am a Vaadin beginner...

Is it possible to preserve session data if the application is initialized again ?

I am asking because I tried to set something to the http session on after page refresh that was gone.

```
WebApplicationContext ctx = (WebApplicationContext) this.getContext();
HttpSession session = ctx.getHttpSession();
Object attribute = session.getAttribute("user"); // <- always gets flushed
```

I would like to use this approach for user authentication.
How to accomplish this best ?

Comment: In your `web.xml` file, what's the `session-timeout` tag's value ?

Comment: What do you mean by initialized again? Calling Application.close()?

Answer (score 3):

It is totally normal that the attribute gets flushed when the app is initialized again because when the app gets initialized again a new Context gets created.
So i would suggest you to use http-cookies instead of adding the attribute to the session itself because this is (as far as i know) the default way to accomplish the "remember-me" feature on websites. Also you have the ability to set the expire date of the cookies.

As a security hint i would recommend you not to use data for user authentication across sessions, which can be easily figured out and abused.

Furthermore i found an article and an addon which deal with cookies:

[Book of Vaadin - explaining how to set Cookies](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.httpservletrequestlistener.html)

[Vaadin Addon which deals with Cookies](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/browsercookies)